# Comparing request.path to a string in Django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I've been messing around with Django for a bit and I ran into this issue, where the comparison in the if labeled below, returns false, when they're both the same string.
If request.path is /test/ then "/{{values|lower}}/" is also /test/ yet they're not equal. Why is this the case?

```
<form class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-toggle btn-block" action="" method="POST">
    {% for i in name %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input {% cycle name.0 name.1 name.2 name.3 name.4 as values %}
            // HERE
            {% if press == values or request.path == "/{{values|lower}}/" %} 
                class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block m-2 active" 
            {% else %} 
                class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block m-2" 
            {% endif %}
        type="Submit" name="{{values}}" value="{{values}}"/>

        // THESE TWO LINES PRINT THE STRINGS ON PAGE
        {{request.path}}
        /{{values|lower}}/

    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: You can't just variable syntax inside a tag.

Comment: Just tried it without and it doesn't work still. This still returns false: {% if request.path == "/values|lower/" %}

Comment: Yes, well that will compare the path with the literal string "/values|lower/".

Comment: Yes, I figured, but the other ways I've tried simply result in error. Is there a way to add the forward slashes?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to get rid of the slashes from request.path with: `request.path|cut:'/'` Now it returns true if compared to values|lower. If anyone has a better solution, I'd be more than happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You better use custom template tags.

1. Create `templatetags` folder inside your app with the same level of `views.py`
2. Put `__init__.py` in that folder with blank content
3. Create new file eg. my_extras.py

```
#my_extras.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='to_str')
def to_str(value):
    return str(value)
```

4. Open up your HTML template
5. Add `{% load my_extras %}` at to top of your template
6. Now to compare path to string. Do something like

```
{% if request.path|to_str==<another_string_to_comparre> %}
Do your stuff here
{% endif %}
```

**Don't forget to restart your server.**

Comment: Invalid filter: 'to_str'